# Issue Installing h5py for Parallel HDF5 with mpi4py

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py, mpi4py

I am trying to build h5py from source with support for parallel HDF5. I built MPICH 3.2 along with HDF5 1.8.16 from source. In the case of HDF5 I used the --enable-parallel and --enable-shared flags per the instructions on the H5PY site. I then tried to build h5py against parallel HDF5 using the instructions from here on the site:

```
$ export CC=mpicc
$ python setup.py configure --mpi --hdf5=/home/myname/phdf5/1.8.16-gnu/
$ python setup.py build
$ python setup.py install
```

Unfortunately after this I'm unable to import h5py as it fails with the error "undefined symbol: H5Pget_dxpl_mpio" as described in with the full trace below:

```
In [1]: import h5py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e81388eeaef8> in <module>()
----> 1 import h5py

/home/wboyd/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py in <module>()
     32 _errors.silence_errors()
     33 
---> 34 from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
     35 _register_converters()
     36 

h5py/h5r.pxd in init h5py._conv (/home/wboyd/Documents/NSE-CRPG-Codes/h5py-2.6.0/h5py/_conv.c:7722)()
h5py/_objects.pxd in init h5py.h5r (/home/wboyd/Documents/NSE-CRPG-Codes/h5py-2.6.0/h5py/h5r.c:3307)()
h5py/_objects.pyx in init h5py._objects (/home/wboyd/Documents/NSE-CRPG-Codes/h5py-2.6.0/h5py/_objects.c:7682)()
ImportError: /home/wboyd/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/defs.so: undefined symbol: H5Pget_dxpl_mpio
```

After searching around on the web I found this and this issue on the GitHub site, but neither were helpful for me. Has anyone else faced this issue? And does anyone have any idea if (or when) Anaconda may release a version of h5py compatible with parallel HDF5 and mpi4py?

Comment: I've found that I can avoid this issue by simply installing h5py v2.5 instead of v2.6. Although this isn't the most satisfying get around, it seems to work.